# What is the general definition of thickness of a strange attractor?

Tags: dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

In [Chaosbook](http://chaosbook.org), at page 56, it is asked to find the *thickness* of Rössler strange attractor, by some means. However, up to this point, the book have only defined the thickness of an Henon map, as the coefficient of the $x_{n-1}$ term in the evolution of a specific sequence.

**Question:**

What is the general definition of *thickness* of a strange attractor ?

Edit: I'm using the version 13.5 of the book (the unstable version).
(Upon request, here is the exact question)

[image]

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484549/2451